# R - create list from dataframe and print in markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, lapply

here is my dataframe

```
dt <-
  data.frame(
    year = c(2018, 2019, 2020),
    sales = c(123, 987, 852)
  )
```

In my markdown document I print data this way

```
datatable(
  dt,
  escape = F,
  rownames = F,
  filter = 'top',
  options = list(
    pageLength = 999,
    dom = "t",
    columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")),
    ordering = T)
) %>%
  formatCurrency(c("sales"), digits = 1)
```

My actual dataframe is much bigger, I'd like to split it by year and print each year in a separate datatable. Also I'd like to print h4 header for each section.

I experimented with lapply this way, but I can't make it to print in markdown and I don't know how to add that header.

```
t_list <-
  lapply(split(dt, dt$year), function(df) {

    datatable(
      df,
      escape = F,
      rownames = F,
      filter = 'top',
      options = list(
        pageLength = 999,
        dom = "t",
        columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")),
        ordering = T)
    ) %>%
      formatCurrency(c("sales"), digits = 1)
})
```

Comment: Try not assigning `lapply` call or call the variable, `t_list` on its own line. By the way `lapply`+`split` can be replaced with `by`: `by(dt, dt$year, function(df) ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `htmltools::tagList`:

````
```{r}
library(DT)
t_list <-
  lapply(split(dt, dt$year), function(df) {
    year <- unique(df$year)
    htmltools::tagList(htmltools::h4(year),datatable(
      df,
      escape = F,
      rownames = F,
      filter = 'top',
      options = list(
        pageLength = 999,
        dom = "t",
        columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")),
        ordering = T)
    ) %>%
      formatCurrency(c("sales"), digits = 1))
})
htmltools::tagList(t_list)

```
````